# Python - Jupyter Notebook - Import function from another file

Tags: python, function

I am using Jupyter on AEN (Anaconda Enterprise Notebook).
I have 2 files. 1st is called Main which is where I'll write all my codes and the other on is called "Functions" which I have made to write all my defined functions.

For the sake of simplicity, I have defined a function as follows and saved this notebook as a .py file.

```
def test():
   print("This is my first function")
```

Now in my main notebook I am trying to import the functions using

```
from Functions import *
```

Which seems to be syntactically correct as it is not throwing any errors but when I create a new cell and try to call my function, test(), it throws an error saying it is not defined.

I next tried to import the function specifically by `from Functions import test`
which is when it threw the following error `ImportError: cannot import name 'test'`.

My Functions notebook doesn't have any other syntax and it is the first time I am attempting this. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried `import Functions` and seen if that works?

Comment: Yupp tried that too. The .py file is imported as I can run the dir(Functions) command. It just doesn't seem to read the defined functions inside the file

Comment: You are mistaken on how to import from notebooks. Breaking down your post .... "My Functions notebook doesn't have any other syntax and it is the first time I am attempting this." Always write out the full name of files with extensions. Earlier in your post, you simply said, 'the other on is called "Functions" '. Most people reading this would assume you meant `Functions.py` as that is how importing works in Python. You write Python code purely in text files that have `.py` extensions and import from them and not notebooks.  ...

Comment: <continued> For importing from notebooks, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/import-jupyter-notebook-script-into-a-python-script/11747/2?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/run-ipynb-from-python-file-keeping-imports-and-variables/13224/2?u=fomightez). Importing from notebooks requires more than what underlies the typical import mechanisms you probably have been encountering reading about `import` and python.